# Android Studio - Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to use the newest version of gradle for android studio which is 1.3.0.

http://android-developers.blogspot.ro/2015/07/get-your-hands-on-android-studio-13.html

Unfortunately I have problems while trying to update the gradle version. Previous version of gradle was 1.2.3 and now  wanted to update this to 1.3.0.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error:Cannot access first() element from an empty List
```

I have also updated to Android Studio 1.3 and i'm currently using the following build tools:

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"
```

I tried deleting gradle and .gradle dirs from my project and also the .gradle dir from user home dir, but with no success.

Even I tried going to File -> Invalidate caches/restart but still no solution.

Comment: try to use 24.3.3 buildToolsVersion

Comment: buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3" is not stable

Comment: @AndoMasahashi buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3" are the latest. I think my problem was in the gradle itself, because I was specifying another classpath in it. I'm closing this question...

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue using gradle 1.3.1 and buildtools 23.0.1. I found that it was due to an old version of bintray-release. This issue is fixed in 0.3.4+.

```
classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.3.4'
```

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the error '**Error:Cannot access first() element from an empty List'** while compiling the 'Drive Database Sync' sample project on git.

Solution : The issue was because of bintray version and I resolved the issue by using the following gradle.build -

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.3.4'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```